# Confusion regarding prototype in javascript object

Tags: javascript

From what I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work), in JS, the prototype refers to the Object that its constructor functions refer to.

So, let's say,

```
function Dog(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Dog.prototype.bark = function(){alert("Woof");}
```

That means now, the Dog's prototype has a `bark` property.

```
var dog = new Dog("Doggo");
dog.bark();
```

Works fine and alerts `Woof`

However, when I add,

```
function Cat(name){
    this.name = name;
}

var cat = new Cat("Little kitten");
cat.bark(); //Nothing happens, why?
```

Both Dog and Cat's prototype point to the same Object.prototype for now (kinda like how Object class is the superclass of all created classes in JAVA, I know prototypes and classes aren't the same but the structure is similar).

So when I am modifying Dog's prototype by adding the `bark` property, it should reflect in Cat as well because they point to the same Object.prototype which is getting modified? What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Your assertion that both functions point to the same prototype object is wrong. They each have distinct prototype objects.

Comment: You can verify that: `console.log(Dog.prototype === Cat.prototype)` (it'll be "false")

Comment: When the constructor function is *defined* it receives a freshly made prototype object. I think that there are abundant examples on the internet on how to correctly set up prototypal inheritance in JavaScript. It has even become easier with the `class...extends` syntax.

Comment: @Pointy okay, Dog.prototype===Cat.prototype prints false. I am not sure why, because I don't have any other Constructors here and the Objects.prototype is like the base prototype of all JS objects, so shouldn't they point to it? Also, dog.prototype===cat.prototype prints true. Ugh JS is confusing.

Comment: The prototype of the Object function is *also* a distinct object. Unless you explicitly assign the prototype of one function to another, **every** function has a distinct prototype object. `Object.prototype` has nothing to do with any other function's prototype object. Instances created by constructors do **not** have a `prototype` property unless you make an assignment explicitly. You might want to read some tutorials about JavaScript prototypes and inheritance; it's *nothing* like Java inheritance.

Comment: (Actually `Object.prototype` *indirectly* affects other prototypes, because everything has `Object.prototype` on the prototype chain (usually). But it's still a distinct object.)

Comment: @Pointy okay, so in the immediate level, the function prototype refers to the prototype object freshly created at time of function declaration & that's why it Dog.prototype===Cat.prototype prints false? Thanks, I'll read up more on this.

Comment: @Little_idiot Yes, precisely.